# Searching an ArrayList

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I'm a bit stuck on what to do after a certain part since making some of my code. It's supposed to put a text file through an ArrayList and then the user should have the ability to type a team name and it should add up how many times they pop up in the text file. But for the life of me I am stuck on how to proceed after what I have.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  ArrayList<String> mlb = new ArrayList<String>();
  Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File("WorldSeriesWinners.txt"));  // Declares the scanner to read from the file.      
  int Count = 0;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userInput;


   while (fileReader.hasNext()){
       // While loop to continue to read while there is another line.
       mlb.add(fileReader.nextLine());
   }
   System.out.println("Enter a championship team you are looking up(1903-2009).");
   userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

   for(String team : mlb){ // Will run through the file and display the ArrayList.
       if(team.contains(userInput))
          System.out.println(team);
```

Comment: You're close. Instead of printing out team inside of your enhanced for loop, try incrementing your count variable, then print out the value of count after the loop and see what it equals. You could also cheat and just use [Collections.frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)...

Comment: Why read the entire file and then loop through it when you can do the search while reading the file (in one swap) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add up the number of times userInput appears in the ArrayList.

```
int count = 0;
for(String team : mlb){ // Will run through the file and display the ArrayList.
   if(team.contains(userInput))
      count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Wow... I feel dumb, I can't believe using that just didn't come across my mind. Thank you. I was stumped over something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [SolR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for searching.

> Solr is the popular, blazing fast open source enterprise search
>   platform from the Apache Lucene project. Its major features include
>   powerful full-text search, hit highlighting, faceted search, dynamic
>   clustering, database integration, rich document (e.g., Word, PDF)
>   handling, and geospatial search. Solr is highly scalable, providing
>   distributed search and index replication, and it powers the search and
>   navigation features of many of the world's largest internet sites...

It will allow you to create queries and search through your record.

You can also use SolR through [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj):

> Solrj is a java client to access solr. It offers a java interface to
>   add, update, and query the solr index.